# Accessing MySQL database from 32-bit app on 64-bit Windows

Tags: c++, mysql, windows

I want to access a MySQL database from a 32-bit (legacy) program I am developing. I have installed the latest version of MySQL (5.7.19) and configured it successfully. It has been installed on a 64-bit Windows 7 system using the MySQL Windows installer. I did not notice any option to install 32-bit support during the installation.

My 32-bit program now includes and uses items from `mysql.h`. It compiles OK in Visual Studio (Community 2015 version)... but it does not link - it cannot find _mysql_server_init and dozens of other functions in libmysql.lib.

Is this a clash between my 32-bit program and a (presumably) 64-bit version of libmysql.lib? How can I resolve it - do I need to uninstall the 64-bit MySQL installation entirely, and replace it with a 32-bit version... or is there a simpler solution?

Comment: You need to use the libraries of a 32 bit version. You do not need to uninstall your server for that, you can access a 64 bit server with a 32 bit library/client. While (32 bit) libraries are included in any (32 bit) server distribution (you can just download and extract them), you can also download them seperately as [Connector/C](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-c/en/connector-c-introduction.html)

Comment: This led me directly to the solution - if you want to provide it as an answer, I'll give it a tick :-)